# tmux equivalent of screen's 'at' command?

Tags: tmux

GNU `screen` has a command, `at`, which lets you control other sessions by sending *screen* commands to them. Does `tmux` have something like that? I tried `send-prefix` and `send-keys`, but those send keys to the process running *inside* tmux; you can't use them to control tmux itself.

Trying to send a control command by doing something like this:

```
send-keys -t main:1 "tmux select-window -t :1" ENTER
```

doesn't work if the inner process is something other than a shell. And it also fails if you're sending the keys from a linked session, even when the inner process is a shell. (In that case your current session is the one affected.)

Comment: In general, the way to “script” *tmux* is to just issue commands through invoking the `tmux` binary; this works even when the command is run from outside any *tmux* session (as long as you supply any non-default `-L` or `-S` values so it can find the correct server). There should be no need to use `send-keys` and hope that the receiving pane has an appropriate shell listening. Is there some reason you can not run the `tmux select-window -t main:1` directly? Alternateively, `bind-key C-n select-window -t main:1` should work as a binding (adjust the key as desired).

Comment: Ah, yes, that works as I want. I assumed for some reason the `select-window` command would be done in the context of my current session and link me to that target window, rather than affect the target session separately. I guess I tried everything but the most straightforward option. Thanks. :) Would you mind promoting your comment to an answer, so I can mark it accepted? Then anyone else with the same question will find an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is optional, the target window specifier that *tmux* window commands accept (i.e. for their `-t` and `-s` options) can directly specify an window in any session. The syntax for a target window works like this:

- *session*`:`*window* where

  - *session* is

    - the specifier for a client (specifies the current session of that client), or
    - an exact, prefix, or *fnmatch(3)* (i.e. “glob”) match for a session name, and
  - *window* is

    - a window index, or
    - an exact, prefix, or *fnmatch(3)* for a window name under *session*.
- *window* (only if there is no colon in the specifier) where

  - *window* is as above, except that it is restricted to the current session.

The second form is probably the most commonly used form, but it sounds like you want the first form in your case.

You should be able to run this command:

```
tmux select-window -t main:1
```

from anywhere to achieve your goal. For example, it will work from a shell script that is executed completely outside the context of a *tmux* session (e.g. via *cron*)—as long as you supply any non-default `-L` or `-S` `tmux` option values so that the command can find the server’s socket.

You can also do it as a binding (e.g. in a `~/.tmux.conf` file or at a *tmux* `:` prompt; adjust the key specifier as desired):

```
bind-key C-m select-window -t main:1
```

You could then type your Prefix and C-m in any client attached to any session in any server that has this binding and it will switch the session matching `main` to its window at index 1.

---

The “target specifier” syntax is described in the “Commands” section of the *tmux* manpage (search for the first occurrence of `target-client`, `target-session`, `target-window`, or `target-pane` to find the relevant descriptions).

I have never used *screen*’s `at` command, but it also looks like it has iteration features. There is currently no direct match for that in *tmux*, but it should be fairly easy to “script” by parsing the output of `list-clients`, `list-sessions`, `list-windows`, and `list-panes` (newer versions of *tmux* have the `-F` option for these commands that can help generate output that it is easier to parse).